# Sound manager for Android

Tags: java, android, singleton, audio

I created a singleton class for managing sound effects on Android. This class will only be instanced and loaded once at the beginning, and each activity will use the loaded songs.

I don't know either if this is the good approach for Singleton, nor if this is the good way to play sounds in Android. This is working like a charm, and I'm wondering about the resource utilizations.

```
public class SoundManager {

    private static SoundManager mInstance;

    private SoundPool mSoundPool;

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap;

    private Vector<Integer> mAvailibleSounds = new Vector<Integer>();
    private Vector<Integer> mKillSoundQueue = new Vector<Integer>();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean mMuted = false;

    private static final int MAX_STREAMS = 2;
    private static final int KILL_AFTER = 3000;

    public static final int SOUND_SELECT = 0;
    public static final int SOUND_LOCKED = 1;


    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    private SoundManager(Context context) {
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        loadSounds(context);
    }

    public static SoundManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new SoundManager(context);
            Log.d("SPARTA", "Instanciation");
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
    * Load all sounds and put them in their respective keys.
    * @param context
    */
    private void loadSounds(Context context){
        addSound(context, SOUND_SELECT, R.raw.metallic_knock);
        addSound(context, SOUND_LOCKED, R.raw.licorice);
    }


    /**
    * Put the sounds to their correspondig keys in sound pool.
    * @param context
    * @param key
    * @param soundID
    */
    public void addSound(Context context, int key, int soundID) {
        mAvailibleSounds.add(key);
        mSoundPoolMap.put(key, mSoundPool.load(context, soundID, 1));
    }

    /**
    * Find sound with the key and play it
    * @param key
    */
    public void playSound(int key) {
        if(mMuted)
        return;

        //If we have the sound
        if(mAvailibleSounds.contains(key)) {

            //We play it
            int soundId = mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(key), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);

            mKillSoundQueue.add(soundId);

            //And schedule the current sound to stop after set milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!mKillSoundQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        mSoundPool.stop(mKillSoundQueue.firstElement());
                    }
                }
            }, KILL_AFTER);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Initialize the control stream with the activity to music
    * @param activity
    */
    public static void initStreamTypeMedia(Activity activity){
        activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    /**
    * Is sound muted
    * @param muted
    */
    public void setMuted(boolean muted) {
        this.mMuted = muted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the corrected version : https://gist.github.com/FR073N/9902559

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I totally agree with Ocelot20, but wanted to point out some more things and provide some comments of my own about some things that has been already mentioned:

#### About `mAvailableSounds`:

- **Vector is deprecated**, use `List` (interface) and `ArrayList` (implementation) instead.

  ```
  private List<Integer> mAvailibleSounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ```
- Does the order of the sounds matter in the `mAvailableSounds` list? No. Use a `HashSet` instead:

  ```
  private Set<Integer> mAvailibleSounds = new HashSet<Integer>();
  ```
- Discard the `mAvailibleSounds` variable entirely and use `mSoundPoolMap.containsKey()` instead.

#### Mapping int to int...

You have used `@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")` to suppress a warning. However, you should know that there is some performance benefit in using a `SparseArray` rather than a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.

You create a mapping from integer to integer, by using your own keys. I don't see the need of this, honestly. Instead you can declare the `R.raw.metallic_knock` and similar as constants, such as:

```
public static final int SOUND_KNOCK = R.raw.metallic_knock;
```

#### Flexibility

Your class seems to be coded in a way intended to be quite flexible, which would be good, but this code is limited to your project only:

```
private void loadSounds(Context context){
    addSound(context, SOUND_SELECT, R.raw.metallic_knock);
    addSound(context, SOUND_LOCKED, R.raw.licorice);
}
```

If you would like to make another project and use this class, you would have to copy it and change those values. That's not a good idea. Programmers hate copy-pasting code within their projects. This class could be made more flexible by not making it dependent of which project is using it. The best way to do that would be to store the constants in a project-specific class, and that the project calls your `SoundManager` class with the resource-ids (such as `R.raw.licorice`).

Currently, if you've forgotten to call `addSound` for a sound but try to play it directly with `playSound`, you wouldn't hear anything. You could save yourself some debugging time from making it either log a warning or try to play a sound with that id. Using the `R.raw` values directly would help with this.

#### Some final words

As you've said yourself: **This is working like a charm**. Your code works, be happy! Really, I mean it.

Comment: Indeed, mAvailableSounds was useless. I get rid of that and used mSoundPoolMap as a SparseIntArray instead. Flexbility wise, I created another class loading all my sounds.

Comment: @FR073N Good work! Welcome back whenever you need more code reviewed.

Answer (score 8):

Let me start by saying I have very limited Android experience. That said, I did look into the `SoundPool` class a bit and have some questions/comments about your implementation:

1. If you aren't already aware of some of the reasons why people consider Singletons an anti-pattern, I suggest you do some research on the topic and make sure you're ok with the downsides.
2. Your class, for the most part, seems to be wrapping a `SoundPool` with a key value pair structure despite `SoundPool` already being a key value pair structure. I would imagine you could do away with most of this class and just use the `SoundPool` class directly.
3. If you don't want to use `SoundPool` directly for some reason, why not at least use the soundId as a key? It already appears to be unique, and it's what the calling code probably wants anyway. If not, you may want to do some checking to make sure that duplicate keys aren't entered, or take the key assignment out of the hands of the caller and simply return an id as the result of the `addSound` function.
4. Using both `mSoundPoolMap` and `mAvailibleSounds` means you have to manage keys in two locations which could lead to them getting out of sync or some confusion as to why there are two fields holding the same information. Using only `mSoundPoolMap` would be sufficient and avoid duplication. [This](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/mutually-exclusive-properties) highly voted question isn't quite the same, but it touches on a lot of good points why this kind of duplication can be bad.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer pointed out what others have explained. I could have accepter your answer as well, but the others gave me a little more information. Just one thing, for point 3, I used mSoundPoolMap to prevent from using the SoundPool load method each time. But you're true when you say that mAvailableSounds had the same function.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting doing away with caching if it was necessary, I was suggesting that you don't need to create a new key when `soundId` already existed and provides a direct map to what the consumer probably already wants to find a sound by (since they ask for it by `soundId` also).

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Ocelot20, I have quite a lot of Android experience, and this answer will focus on only one thing, namely:

## Getting rid of the Singleton pattern in Android

Quote from a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3888560/1310566):

> Although the app context can be considered a singleton itself, it is framework-managed and has a well defined life-cycle, scope, and access path. Hence I believe that if you do need to manage app-global state, it should go here, nowhere else. For anything else, rethink if you really need a singleton object, or if it would also be possible to rewrite your singleton class to instead instantiate small, short-lived objects that perform the task at hand.

In your Android.XML file there is the tag `<application>`. This tag can have the property `android:name`. This property can be set to a classname that extends `android.app.Application`.

```
<application android:name="com.mypackage.MyApplication" ...>
```

The `com.mypackage.MyApplication` class is very easy to make, simply this would be enough:

```
public class Register extends Application {
}
```

But that's kind of boring, so you'd probably would want a `public void doSomething()` method, or - in your example:

```
public class Register extends Application {
    private SoundManager soundManager;

    public SoundManager getSoundManager() {
        if (soundManager == null) {
             // Application extends Context so just pass along 'this'!
             soundManager = new SoundManager(this); 
        }
        return soundManager;
    }
}
```

#### How to get an instance of the `MyApplication` class then?

When your application starts, if you have specified the `android:name` property then Android will create an instance of the classname that you put here. This instance will be available through the Android `Context` that gets passed around to all Views, Activities and Fragments.

That said, it is very easy to get access to the instance of `com.mypackage.MyApplication` from more or less anywhere, whether you have an `Activity`, a `View` or a `Fragment`. (If you haven't used Fragments yet by the way, [you really should](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) - there is a [compatibility library available](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) if you are targeting API <= 10).

All your Android Activities have the `getApplication` method, this retreives an instance of an `Application` class, in your case it will return the `MyApplication` instance.

All Android Views have the `getContext` method, which has a `getApplicationContext` method which will return an `Application` instance, again; this will be your `MyApplication` instance.

#### Examples

In a method in your activity:

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
myApp.doSomething();
```

When you have no `Activity` nearby but instead have a `View` or another way to get a `Context`:

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
myApp.doSomething();
```

In a fragment, use either `getView` or `getActivity` and then use one of the methods described above (`getApplication` or `getContext().getApplicationContext()`)

**That**, my friend, is how you avoid making your own singletons in Android. This is *the* recommended way of doing it, and it *can* also be used for passing data from one activity to another (when you are unable to use `getExtra` and `putExtra` to pass data between activities).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that way. This answers my problematique of creating a singleton class in Android.

Answer (score 5):

1. I agree with *Simon* that `Vector` is deprecated and should be changed but its thread-safety is used in the case of `mKillSoundQueue` (it's used by multiple threads), so be careful. If you change it make sure that it will remain thread-safe. The name of the field also suggests that it's a queue, so I'd probably go with a thread-safe [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementation here.
2. Just a question: wouldn't it be safer using `soundId` here too? (It have to be `final` for that.)

   > ```
   > if (!mKillSoundQueue.isEmpty()) {
   >     mSoundPool.stop(mKillSoundQueue.firstElement());
   > }
   > ```

   If I'm right the following is the same and you could get rid of the `mKillSoundQueue` field completely:

   ```
   mSoundPool.stop(soundId);
   ```

   [`SoundPool.stop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#stop%28int%29) says the following:

   > If the stream is not playing, it will have no effect.
3. Using `m` prefixes to access fields not really necessary and it's just noise. Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from fields.

   > ```
   > private static SoundManager mInstance;
   > ```
4. I'd use a `_MILLIS` (or anything which is appropriate) postfix here for better clarity:

   > ```
   > private static final int KILL_AFTER = 3000;
   > ```
5. This:

   > ```
   > mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   > ```

   could be in the same line as the declaration:

   ```
   private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap = 
       new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();;
   ```
6. It's really bad formatting:

   > ```
   > if(mMuted)
   > return;
   > ```

   Indentation of the `return` statement would make it readable.
7. According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-142311.html#430)

   > `if` statements always use braces `{}`.

   Omitting them is error-prone.
8. Comments like this are just noise, so they're unnecessary, remove them:

   > ```
   > * @param key
   > ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
9. Instead of comments like

   > ```
   > //If we have the sound
   > if(mAvailibleSounds.contains(key)) {
   > ```

   and

   > ```
   >  //And schedule the current sound to stop after set milliseconds
   > mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   > ```

   You could create explanatory variables and methods.

   ```
   boolean hasSound = mAvailibleSounds.contains(key);
   if (hasSound) {
       ...
   ```

   and `scheduleCurrentSoundStop()`.

   References:

   - *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Bad Comments*, *Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable*, p67
   - *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*
   - *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*
10. In the first case above I'd use a [guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) to make the code flatten:

    ```
    boolean hasSound = mAvailibleSounds.contains(key);
    if (hasSound) {
        return;
    }
    ...
    ```

Comment: Your answer and Simon's really improved my code. I accepted his answer because I learned something about singleton with Android, but I could have accepted yours as well. Just one last question, about the third point : when should we use the m prefix ?

Comment: @FR073N: Sure, thanks for the feedback! (If you have time feel free to help [graduating the site](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1572/7076). I'm sure that you can find another useful questions and answers on the site to [vote on](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/612/7076)).

Comment: @FR073N: I don't know any valid use-cases for the `m` prefix right now, nothing comes to mind.