# Helper function to return a string based on passed object and some defined rules

Tags: java

In my application, a notification should be displayed when a chat message arrives. 
 There are some rules which decide what notification message is to be displayed.

I have created a helper method which takes a `ChatMessage` object and returns the message to be displayed in the notification.

How can I refactor or improve this piece of code? 
Any feedback will be appreciated.

```
private String getNotificationDisplayString(ChatMessage chat) {
    String message;
    boolean isUpdateMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG));
    if (isUpdateMessage) {
        // for update message
        UserRelationshipInfo relationshipInfo = UserRelationshipInfoManger.getInstance().getInfo(chat.getUserId());
        boolean isUserMyFriend = (relationshipInfo != null && relationshipInfo.getSource() == SOURCE_FRIEND);
        message = Resources.string(isUserMyFriend ? R.string.text_user_is_friend : R.string.text_user_is_stranger);
    } else {
        boolean isDirectMessage = (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE);
        boolean isTextMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG));

        if (isDirectMessage) {
            // for direct message (special case)
            String messageName = Resources.string(getMessageType(chat.getTag()));
            // message = "<name> sent you a direct <image/video/etc>"
            message = String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_direct_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName(), messageName);
        } else if (isTextMessage) {
            // for text (non-direct)
            message = new TextInfo(chat).getText();
        } else {
            // for non-text (non-direct)
            // message = "<name> sent you a message"
            message = String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName());
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean isUpdateMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG));
```

Consider using a `chat.isUpdateMessage()` method for that logic.

---

```
UserRelationshipInfo relationshipInfo = UserRelationshipInfoManger.getInstance().getInfo(chat.getUserId());
```

**Singleton pattern detected!** I would not recommend using the singleton pattern, I am quite certain that there's a better way to do this, as I don't know the entire context of your code I am not sure which method would be the best, but to get you started take a look at [a previous answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45751/sound-manager-for-android/45772#45772).

---

```
boolean isUserMyFriend = (relationshipInfo != null && relationshipInfo.getSource() == SOURCE_FRIEND);
```

Again, consider using as method such as `relationshipInfo.isMyFriend()`

---

```
message = Resources.string(isUserMyFriend ? R.string.text_user_is_friend : R.string.text_user_is_stranger);
```

Again, this seems like you have a `Context` stored in a static variable somewhere. I wouldn't recommend that. Tell, don't ask. If something needs your context, tell them about it. Don't have them ask some other object/place about it.

---

```
boolean isDirectMessage = (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE);
boolean isTextMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG));
```

Two methods: `chat.isDirectMessage()` and `chat.isTextMessage()`.

---

```
String messageName = Resources.string(getMessageType(chat.getTag()));
```

`getMessageType` should be a method in the `ChatMessage` class. `chat.getMessageType()`. And again, I'm not a fan of the `Resources.string` method as it tells me you got a static Context object somewhere.

---

```
message = String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName());
```

When using Android resources, there's a special method for combining the getString with String.format. See [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 3):

Some simple pointers...

- You have `boolean` assignments that are only used once, for conciseness it may be preferable to inline them:

  ```
  // old
  boolean isUpdateMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG));
  if (isUpdateMessage) 

  // new
  if (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG))
  ```
- Not sure if the getter methods on your `ChatMessage` class can return `null`s or not, but in the unlikely event they do, you may want to practice some defensive coding by switching the `.equals()` around, e.g. `if (TAG_UPDATE_MSG.equals(chat.getTag()))`
- Your comments in the code code snippet are redundant, can consider removing them too for conciseness too.

edit: (prompted by OP's first comment)

Wells, this *shouldn't be* recommended on CR but just for fun, I tried golfing your method and reduced it to a few ternary operators as a 'one-liner':

```
return chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG) ? 
    Resources.string(UserRelationshipInfoManger.getInstance().getInfo(chat.getUserId()).getSource() == SOURCE_FRIEND ? 
        R.string.text_user_is_friend : 
        R.string.text_user_is_stranger) : 
    chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG) ? 
        new TextInfo(chat).getText() : 
        String.format(Resources.string(chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE ? 
            R.string.text_new_direct_message : 
            R.string.text_new_message
        ), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName(), Resources.string(getMessageType(chat.getTag())));
```

The only assumption I made is that the `relationshipInfo` will not return `null`, so I can eliminate the `null`-check when assigning `isUserMyFriend`. Once I got to this golfed version three minor improvements become clearer:

1. You can consider a supplementary method `isUserMyFriend()` in the `UserRelationshipInfoManger` instance to give you a `boolean` value for checking if the user is a friend or not.
2. You can consider a supplementary method `getUserDisplayName()` in the `ChatMessage` class that simply calls `getUserInfo().getDisplayName()`.
3. You are using `chat.getTag()` in a few places, maybe assign a variable to it for compactness?

By implementing these three suggestions, I got down to:

```
T tag = chat.getTag(); // whatever the actual Type is
return tag.equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG) ? 
    Resources.string(UserRelationshipInfoManager.getInstance().isUserMyFriend(chat.getUserId()) ? 
        R.string.text_user_is_friend : 
        R.string.text_user_is_stranger) : 
    tag.equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG) ? 
        new TextInfo(chat).getText() : 
        String.format(Resources.string(chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE ? 
            R.string.text_new_direct_message : 
            R.string.text_new_message
        ), chat.getUserDisplayName(), Resources.string(getMessageType(tag)));
```

I must admit, this is taking things a little to the extreme, and I'm conveniently relying on the assumption that passing extra arguments into `String.format()` will be silently ignored (tested). Otherwise, I'm actually pretty OK with what you have in your question. :)

Comment: I have to veto the boolean inlining :) `isUpdateMessage` is a lot easier/faster to understand than `(chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG))`. But using this technique AND comments is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

There are some Suggestions regarding code :

**1.** Always initialise local variable (some default value or `null`)

```
String message = null;
```

**2.** Don't use unnecessary `else` if you can use `else if` instead

```
if (isUpdateMessage) {...
   } else{
     boolean isDirectMessage = (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE);
        boolean isTextMessage = (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG));

        if (isDirectMessage) {...
       } else if(...
```

You can use `else if` at very first `else`

```
if (isUpdateMessage) {...

   }      
   if (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE) {...

   } else if(...
```

**3.** Don't create new `boolean` if not getting use at more than one place and remove unnecessary parenthesis ( brackets).

```
boolean isDirectMessage = (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE);
                          ^... two brackets not required...^
```

Here `boolean` is not required to create as we can use condition directly in `if` part.

**4.** And always call `.equals()` on constant,  so that if other string (`chat.getTag()` in this case) is `null` then there will not be any `NullPointerException`

```
`chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG)` should be `TAG_TEXT_MSG.equals(chat.getTag())`
```

Please find below method code after incorporating comments :

```
private String getNotificationDisplayString(ChatMessage chat) {
    String message = null;// initialise local variable to null 
    // check if updated message directly and isUpdateMessage removed
    if (TAG_UPDATE_MSG.equals(chat.getTag())) {
        // for update message
        UserRelationshipInfo relationshipInfo = UserRelationshipInfoManger.getInstance().getInfo(chat.getUserId());
        boolean isUserMyFriend = (relationshipInfo != null && relationshipInfo.getSource() == SOURCE_FRIEND);
        message = Resources.string(isUserMyFriend ? R.string.text_user_is_friend : R.string.text_user_is_stranger);
    }else if (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE) {
            // for direct message (special case)
            String messageName = Resources.string(getMessageType(chat.getTag()));
            // message = "<name> sent you a direct <image/video/etc>"
            message = String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_direct_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName(), messageName);
    } else if (TAG_TEXT_MSG.equals(chat.getTag())) {
            // for text (non-direct)
            message = new TextInfo(chat).getText();         
    } else {
            // for non-text (non-direct)
            // message = "<name> sent you a message"
            message = String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName());
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Rather than initializing Strings to null, I found it better and less Exception happy to initialize them to ""

Comment: *Always initialise local variable (some default value or null)* - I disagree with that. In fact, I find it better to do the opposite. Don't initialize it unless you need to. IDEs will show a warning on your initialization stating that the assignment is not used, because it will get overridden by the next assignment. And avoiding initial initialization might allow you to have the variable `final` which has never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Same as h.j.k that you don't have to store the booleans for an if.

Return directly in stead of saving into message.

Result is like this :

```
private String getNotificationDisplayString(ChatMessage chat) {
    if (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_UPDATE_MSG)) {
        // for update message
        UserRelationshipInfo relationshipInfo = UserRelationshipInfoManger.getInstance().getInfo(chat.getUserId());
        boolean isUserMyFriend = (relationshipInfo != null && relationshipInfo.getSource() == SOURCE_FRIEND);
        return Resources.string(isUserMyFriend ? R.string.text_user_is_friend : R.string.text_user_is_stranger);
    } else if (chat.getType() == DIRECT_MESSAGE) {
        // for direct message (special case)
        String messageName = Resources.string(getMessageType(chat.getTag()));
        // message = "<name> sent you a direct <image/video/etc>"
        return String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_direct_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName(), messageName);
    } else if (chat.getTag().equals(TAG_TEXT_MSG)) {
        // for text (non-direct)
        return new TextInfo(chat).getText();
    } 
    // for non-text (non-direct)
    // message = "<name> sent you a message"
    return String.format(Resources.string(R.string.text_new_message), chat.getUserInfo().getDisplayName());
}
```