# Android Global Variable Setup

Tags: java, android

I am using the Android library Retrofit for networking in my app. The library calls for creating a RestAdapter for making service calls. I want to use this same instance of the RestAdapter for all of my service calls. How is my setup for this scenario?

Extending Application:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private RestClient restClient = null;

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }

    public void initRestClient() {
        if (restClient == null) {
            restClient = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASE_URL).build().create(RestClient.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Initializing instance and making sure I have access to the instance in all my Activities, without explicitly having to get it for each Activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected RestClient restClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((CustomApplication) this.getApplication()).initRestClient();
        restClient = ((CustomApplication) this.getApplication()).getRestClient();
    }
}
```

Then all my Activities will extend BaseActivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem, and a common solution is dependency injection. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern in which one or more
>   dependencies (or services) are injected, or passed by reference, into
>   a dependent object (or client) and are made part of the client's
>   state. The pattern separates the creation of a client's dependencies
>   from its own behavior, which allows program designs to be loosely
>   coupled and to follow the dependency inversion and single
>   responsibility principles.

One dependency framework for Android is [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/):

> Dependency injection isn't just for testing. It also makes it easy to
>   create reusable, interchangeable modules. You can share the same
>   `AuthenticationModule` across all of your apps. And you can run
>   `DevLoggingModule` during development and `ProdLoggingModule` in
>   production to get the right behavior in each situation.

Beside's @janos's great point about inheritance being for *is-a* relationships, you can imagine `BaseActivity` slowly getting cluttered with methods and fields that some activities need, and other don't. Eventually it all becomes a mess.

With dependency injection, an activity's reliance upon a `RestAdapter` can be made clear:

```
class SomeActivity extends Activity {
  private final RestAdapter restAdapter;

  @Inject
  public SomeActivity(final RestAdapter restAdapter) {
    this.restAdapter = restAdapter;
  }

  ...
}
```

And now you can unit test `SomeActivity` with other `RestAdapter`s.

Making the `RestAdapter` a singleton requires only an attribute:

```
@Provides @Singleton RestAdapter provideRestAdapter() {
  return new RestAdapter.Builder()
      .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
      .build()
      .create(RestClient.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the dependency injection suggestion. I've spend the past few days researching DI/Dagger, and this is the solution I'm going with.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with both [@mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka) and [@kyle-falconer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32292/kyle-falconer). In fact the two points are very similar, because dependency injection frameworks usually work by giving you singletons by default. Mjolka's suggestion of adopting [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) will be good long-term solution and definitely worth the time investment. Kyle's suggestion is more of a direct, simple solution you can implement right now.

If you go with Kyle's approach, I would point out the modern way of implementing singletons in Java using an `enum`, that's simpler and more robust:

```
enum SingletonRestClient {
    INSTANCE;

    private final RestClient restClient;

    private SingletonRestClient() {
        restClient = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASE_URL).build().create(RestClient.class);
    }

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }
}
```

You could use this in an activity like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private RestClient restClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        restClient = SingletonRestClient.INSTANCE.getRestClient();
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to do this in all your activities that need the rest client.
But this is still better than forcing all your activities to extend a base activity.

Don't use inheritance just to share data.
The right reason to use inheritance is when there is an *is-a* relationship.
Can you say that `SomeActivity` *is a* `BaseActivity`?
This sounds inevitably wrong, because the very nature of a "base activity" is that there is just one such activity.
A good example would be an `EmployeeActivity` inheriting from a `PersonActivity`,
which could make sense, since an employee really *is a* person.

We don't have more details about your context.
If there is no *is-a* relationship between the classes involved,
then don't use inheritance, and prefer composition instead:
let each class that needs a rest client get it from the singleton.

Answer (score 4):

The approach of extending `Application` is what I also [have been recommending](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45751/sound-manager-for-android/45772#45772) many times. It is recommended though to read this whole [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3826905/1310566).

As for your current code, I have one warning: It could theoretically create two objects if called in a multithreaded environment (although I doubt this will happen)

As for your current code, I feel that both these lines are a bit overkill:

```
((CustomApplication) this.getApplication()).initRestClient();
restClient = ((CustomApplication) this.getApplication()).getRestClient();
```

You could change your `getRestClient` to:

```
public RestClient getRestClient() {
    if (restClient == null) {
        restClient = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASE_URL).build().create(RestClient.class);
    }
    return restClient;
}
```

And then this line would be enough:

```
restClient = ((CustomApplication) this.getApplication()).getRestClient();
```

Although it would be better to just initialize the `restClient` once by overriding the [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) method.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need all other Activities to extend `BaseActivity`, though that is one way to do it. What you're looking to do is make your `RestAdapter` a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which can be implemented by having some static singleton class for wrapping your `RestAdapter`.

Here's an example of what that might look like, which was adapted from [Akylah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16518088/940217) which referred to this gist of a [sample singleton](https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992):

```
public class SingletonRestAdapter {
    private static RestAdapter mInstance = null;

    public static RestAdapter getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASE_URL).build().create(RestClient.class);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```