# Proper way to wait end of a service and singleton design

Tags: java, multithreading, android, singleton

My code works fine and I would like to know if I chose the best strategy to implement my code, or if It can written better (more fast, more clear, best use of design pattern, etc).

In my android application `WelcomeActivity`, in the `onCreate` method, I start a really simple service that load data from a file:

```
public class LoadDataService extends IntentService {
    private int result;
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try 
        {
            FileTestSingleton.getInstance(); //this could be long, read from file
            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(LoadDataService.class.getName(), "FILE DATA LOADING ERROR \n" + e);
            result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
        }
        publishResults(result);
    }

    private void publishResults(int result) {
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Some activity after, the user click a button to go to the next step of my APP. The `onCreate` method of `MyNewActivity` need the data from the service, otherwise it's ok to freeze the application, because if the data aren't loaded, nothing can be done. For example, I read that to stop the UI thread is a bad thing, but I need to stop it, otherwise my new activity will not have data to show.

So in my `onCreate`:

```
while (FileTestSingleton.getState()==Semaphore.LOADING)
{
    Thread.sleep(250);          
}
fileTest = FileTestSingleton.getInstance();
```

Is this a proper way to wait?

`Semaphore` is a simple `enum` that I created inside the `FileTestSingleton` class:

```
public enum Semaphore
{
    EMPTY,
    LOADING,
    DONE;
}
private static Semaphore semaphore = Semaphore.EMPTY;
private static FileTestSingleton fileTest;
public static FileTestSingleton getInstance() throws Exception
{
    if (fileTest==null && semaphore!=Semaphore.LOADING)
    {
        semaphore = Semaphore.LOADING;
        fileTest = new FileTestSingleton(); //read from file, really slow
        semaphore = Semaphore.DONE;
    }
    return fileTest;
}
public static Semaphore getState()
{
    return semaphore;
}
```

Why I think that I can't use `AsyncTask`:
The problem is: I load some txt files on the startup in the `WelcomeActivity` that is for 2 seconds on the screen. After the app go in the `MiddleActivity` and the user  in the meantime can choose some options before he starts the final step of the application: `FinalActivity`. This `FinalActivity` need that all the txt files are loaded in the singleton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bug?

The catch block is a bit suspicious here:

> ```
> try 
> {
>     FileTestSingleton.getIstance(); //this could be long, read from file
> } catch (Exception e) 
> {
>     Log.e(LoadDataService.class.getName(), "FILE DATA LOADING ERROR \n" + e);
>     result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
> }
> result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
> publishResults(result);
> ```

When you catch the exception, you set `result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;`,
but execution continues and on the next line comes `result = Activity.RESULT_OK;`.
In short, the method will return with success as if nothing happened.

#### Don't catch `Exception`

Always catch the most specific `Exception` type possible.
By catching something overly generic,
you may not notice when something truly unexpected is thrown.
In most practical situations there is a more specific exception class that you should check.

#### Don't declare a method to throw `Exception`

A method that's declared to throw `Exception` is very poorly designed.
It gives no clue to the caller about the kind of failure that can happen,
and it's impossible to know how to recover from it.
Surely you can think of something more specific,
to give the chance to callers to handle the failure gracefully.

#### Coding style

There is a standard in Java for placing braces:
the opening braces should be on the same line as their statement. Follow this style:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Proper way to wait for end of X

In other words, the proper way to execute a long operation without freezing the client. I think it's using an `AsyncTask`, with a `ProgressDialog`. Here's a rough sketch:

```
class WaitForServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "",
                YourActivity.this.getString(R.string.msg_waiting_for_service), false, true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // the long task -- calling the service
    }
}
```

This won't freeze the UI thread and will let the user know that the app is not dead, but actually doing something.

Comment: Thanks, very precious! Yes, the first was a bug that I didn't notice. What about the Thread.sleep(250); Is it ok?

Comment: Yeah, that's not so good either. I added one more paragraph for that, using an `AsyncTask`. This is how I did before, and it worked very nicely.

Comment: I cannot use `AsyncTask` because like I said, I have to start the file reading in the beginning activity of my app (soon as I can), and this `WelcomeActivity` is just a page with a logo that stay alive for 2 second before to go to the next activity (and the file reading is longer than 2 sec.).

Comment: I don't see how that prevents you from using an `AsyncTask`. Note that the `AsyncTask` I proposed will open a modal `ProgressDialog` which the user can't get out of. When the initialization is finished, the dialog will close, and you can transition to the next activity.  The name "Async" is misleading here, because in fact the operation is very much synchronous. But instead of freezing the UI, it will show a progress dialog, which is a lot friendlier.

Comment: The problem is: I load some txt files on the startup in the `WelcomeActivity` that is for 2 seconds on the screen. After the app go in the `MiddleActivity` and the user  in the meantime can choose some options before he starts the final step of the application: `FinalActivity`. This `FinalActivity` need that all the txt files are loaded in the singleton.

Comment: @Accollativo I am sure that it is still possible to use `AsyncTask`, you just need to use it correctly.

Comment: From what I read, I can use `AsyncTask` only in the same activity, [not over different activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401233/asynctask-over-multiple-activities), that is my case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @janos suggestion about an `AsyncTask` (which is a good suggestion), there's also the approach of using [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

If your `LoadDataService` would have access to an instance of your `Activity`, then it could tell your activity to run some code on the UI thread, for example `yourActivity.handleResults(result);`

I've written a previous answer about [using singleton pattern in Android](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45772/31562).

Most often, Singleton pattern can be completely avoided.

In fact, I'm not convinced your use of Singleton pattern is very good. Can some other code call the constructor `new FileTestSingleton();` ? If so, then it's not really a singleton.

About your `getIstance();` method... What is an *Istance*? Did you mean **Instance**?

Comment: You have to be careful with singletons in Android since they have a different behavior than Java.  The Android runtime can kill and restart an application at any time and the singleton can therefore be randomly wiped out.   It might not matter here, but if a singleton is used as an "in memory" database for example, it would be very bad.

Comment: Thanks @toto2 you get another point. The singleton is used as an "in memory" DB. I didn't use a real DB, because my data are on various txt files, and I just need to read from it (I never write).

@Simon like I replied to @janos, I can't use `AsyncTask`.